# A shortest path with fuel constraints using Floyd-Warshall

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, bellman-ford, floyd-warshall

[image]

I tried to write pseudo-code based on this solution.
But I couldn't understand this part "Once  we have run Bellman-Ford, we can look back at  the results from Floyd-Warshall to determine whice partial paths corresponded to the path found in G'". Can anyone help me to understand this using pseudo-code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at a very simple example, with one gas station.

[image]

Find the shortest path in G' is `start - s - target`

To find the corresponding path in G, look at each hop in the G' path and find the shortest feasible path in G between the nodes in G1 hop'

start - s becomes `start - v1 - s`

s - target becomes `s - v2 - target`

Adding the partial paths together we get the answer

```
start - v1 - s - v2 - target
```

So the pseudo code is

```
Construct G'
Find P' the shortest path in G'
LOOP over hops in P'
    Find Pg shortest path between hop source and hop destination in G
    Add Pg to Ps ( eliminating common vertex )
Output Ps
```